# Is there a way to "re-link" all contacts using some button or other procedure?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts

My contacts come from 3 sources:

1. Google account
2. Facebook
3. Skype

Some of those contacts were automatically linked together so "Joe Smith" appears as one contact instead of three. However, some contacts were not linked automatically.

Is there a button or some other way to tell Android "go scan all contacts from all accounts now and try to re-link them"?

Answer (score 3):

I did this a few months ago by downloading a third-party contacts app, using its (much smarter) merge function, and then uninstalling the app. I can't remember for sure, but I think the app I used was either [Contacts by Contapps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android) or [GO Contacts EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro). There's also [Contact Analyzer 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrew.contactanalyzer2), but there are some reports of it deleting all contacts instead of merging!

Comment: contapps works great!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to do it manually, by going into the contact, pressing Menu, and then Join, and select the contact you want to join it with

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to do this on an Android device, but in the desktop contact manager there is a way.

Log into GMail in your desktop, switch to the `Contacts` view.  Under `More` select "Find & Merge duplicates ...".

This will present a list of all the "duplicates" that Google found.  Handily, you can check/uncheck which ones you want it to merge now, and which to skip.

This assumes that all of the contacts that got slurped into your phone from Skype and Facebook got pushed up to google.

Comment: That will only work for Google account contacts - what I was referring to is this: http://www.stdi.com/stdi/home.nsf/ws/AndroidContact